# How to grab text from the first td with xpath

Tags: xpath, text, html-table

does someone knows how to grab the text from the first td and not the next? And make it 0 if it doesn't have a value:

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:28%;">
    2 plantas··
    &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="width:28%;">
    300m² terreno


    &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the picture above, my code (below) is also grabbing the next td which is a blank space, but I want to grab the one that says "300m2 terreno":

```
terreno=tree.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"planta")]/following-sibling::td/text()')
terreno2=[item.strip() for item in terreno]
terreno3=[]
for casa in terreno2:
    if len(casa)<1: continue
    terreno3.append(float(casa.split('m²')[0]))
```

And I'm getiing for output this:

```
['300m² terreno', '', '', '', '', '', '315m² terreno', '', '', '', '', ''....]
```

Here is the link from my source:
https://www.avisosdeocasion.com/Resultados-Inmuebles.aspx?n=venta-casas-nuevo-leon&PlazaBusqueda=2&Plaza=2

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this xpath :

```
//td[contains(text(),"planta")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()
#                                                     ^
                                             limit to the fisrt 'td'
```